# Renaming a Datastax Solr core

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

Is the OS Solr RENAME command supported in DSE? If yes, will it also rename the underlying Cassandra table? Similarly, is the SWAP command supported? And will it also swap the names of the Cassandra tables?

Any of the two would work for me. I want to replace one of my cores with something else because I found a bug in the bulk loader script that I used (hence, I have incorrect data in the existing core).

I just want to be sure before trying anything in my live cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of swap or rename are supported at the moment.

Comment: It does answer the question, although I have a follow-up: it there a plan to support these in the near future? What do you recommend that I do in my case? I need to keep the existing core available while the new one is being built

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to rename the table using hive or spark. Then recreate your sorl core.